# Create shutdown hook and run it in the same thread in java

Tags: java, shutdown-hook

I know I can add a shutdown hook which will run in a new Thread, but how can I add a shutdown hook for the current thread, if even possible? 
I need some code to be run in the same thread as which created the shutdown hook but I couln't find an answer yet.

edit: some background information:

I'm writing a library which calls CoInitialize from MS COM interface whenever a specific object is created. I want the user to not need to care about uninitializing COM thus I thought I could simply call CoUninitialize in a shutdown hook. But the uninitialization must happen from the same thread as from which it was initialized, so it doesn't work with a shutdown hook.

Comment: The shutdown process belongs to the jvm. What you are asking does not seem feasible. A shutdown hook is just a runnable that the jvm launches prior to exiting

Comment: What? Develop your question. You could just use a while if you want to delay a shutdown.

Comment: Would a `finally` block do what you want?

Comment: @Andy_Turner no, I'm developing a library and thus can't force the user to wrap everything in a try block

Comment: Com interface like MS COM? Do you have that running in a java thread?

Comment: @efekctive yes, using JNA

Comment: I think you are in a lot more trouble than you think. Maybe wrap the JNA call in a try block. Interrupt that thread from a shutdown hook and clean it in the exception handling. If this works let me know I will post it as answer

Comment: @efekctive That wouldn't work as I want the user to not care about threading (which would be a horrible library otherwise). But when I initialize COM from another thread internally, the user wouldn't be able to use COM from his own thread.

Comment: I think you are in a mess.  You need a try/block to interrupt user's thread  from shutdown to avoid creating leaks and other problems. But hopefully I am wrong

Comment: @efekctive yeah well, imo calling com from java is messy altogether :) I'll see if I can find another way around..

Comment: What about using nio/mapped byte buffer between com and jvm? I don't know if what you need from COM can be easily put into bytes but it is worth a look. It seems that the main project is in java so using C# is not an option.

Comment: @efekctive jna handles the communication between com and jvm quiet well, leaves the user with a high level api. Thus I'd prefer to not hack into jna's code introducing bugs etc. I can't imagine how modifying the communication would solve my problem anyways since it's already just one method call what causes the problem

Comment: It would be no jna. sending requests to COM via a memory mapped file using the same user api. COM lives in a non jvm thread so no mess. It would be a rewrite/departure of what you have. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.addShutdownHook`...

> Registers a new **virtual-machine** shutdown hook.

(my bold, see API [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))).

---

Dissecting your questions...

---

> [...]how can I add a shutdown hook for the current thread

There is no such thing as a shutdown hook for any given thread.

You can either simply write the statements you require executing by the end of the `run` implementation, or use a `finally` statement to guarantee their execution after a `try` (and/or a `catch`) statement is executed, within your given thread's `run` implementation.

> I need some code to be run in the same thread as which created the
>   shutdown

That is a different question altogether. 
If you want execution within the same thread creating the shutdown hook, simply add the statements after your `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(someThread);` statement.

Comment: He can not add an already running thread to the shutdown pool. But I may be wrong

Comment: @efekctive I didn't quite understand the question your way... what is the rationale for this interpretation?

Comment: Read he is comments

Comment: I can't add the statements after the `addShutdownHook` since they would be run instantly after the hook was added, but I want them to be run at jvm shutdown, without having a try-finally block

Comment: @LPrc but why don't you just add them to the `Thread` you're passing to `addShutdownHook` then?

Comment: @Mena because the uninitialization of COM needs to happen in the same thread as from which it was initialized. So by creating a new Thread when adding a shutdown hook it wouldn't uninitialize COM correctly (see my edit)

Comment: @LPrc not familiar with COM but you **cannot** add a shutdown hook with a thread that's already running (think initialization of the external process inline with the `run` method, then waiting on some monitor to "proceed" to uninitialization once signaled). So, I can't really think of a solution involving a shutdown hook here.

Comment: @Mena okay, thanks a lot for your effort :) then I can just leave this idea behind and maybe find another solution

Comment: @LPrc no problems, sorry that didn't help.